# iOS and XCode: Issue with certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I've search the web but couldn't find a solution exactly for my problem. I've created a `Development Provisioning Profiles` in `iOS Provisioning Portal` and added it to my iMac. I can successfully deploy applications to my iPhone.

Now I'm trying to deploy the same application from my MacBook Pro. I've installed the profile but gets an error:

> XCode could not find a valid private certificate/valid key-pair for this profile in your keychain

I think that I need a private key from my iMac which I have to import to my MacBook Pro. Right? My question is, where can I find that private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have generated your certificate, Apple requires you to use Keychain Access for generating a certificate signing request (CSR). When you've done this, a private key has been generated in your keychain. 
You got the error above because you don't have transfered this private key between your Macs.

Here is the guide to do so (the link is for mac, but it's the same manipulation). From your iMac :

1. Open Keychain Access in the /Applications/Utilities folder.
2. Select the signing certificates you want to export.
3. Choose File > Export items.
4. Choose Personal Information Exchange (.p12) as the file format and click Save.
5. Enter a password and click OK when done.

Transfer the p12 on your macbook, and :

- Double-click the exported file that has a .p12 extension.

Extracted from :

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/CodeSigning/CodeSigning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011201-CH7-SW17

Comment: As far as I remember, I did not create a certificate in my iMac. Maybe I'm wrong. What name could I look for in the Keychain?

Comment: The certificate is received when you download identity.cer from the dev center, or is downloaded by xcode if you use automatic device provisioning (in the Organizer)

Answer (score 1):

Revoke the current certificate then follow the prompts regarding keychain Access when you go create new and then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use your keychain to create the CSR, and then upload it on the new provisioning portal. Just did it the other day.